# Magento 2 product page show backorder insteed of add to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, product-page, backorder

Hope there is one that can help me out with this problem. I made it years back for M1 but can remember how and now I need it for my M2 website.

On the productpage I want to show backorder insteed of add to cart for all products with the quantity 0 or below. All products with quantity of 1 or more it must show add to cart.

I have allow backorder and notify customers. But to make it more clear I want the cart bottum to display backorder (Bestillingsvare) for the products that are not in stock.

It M2 2.4.3-p1

Comment: Anyone who can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model with the below code and use it in the phtml. You can get the product's SKU from the registry.

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Extension\ViewModel;

use Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\GetStockItemConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\SalesChannelInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\StockResolverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class BackorderHelper implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var StockResolverInterface
     */
    private StockResolverInterface $stockResolver;
    /**
     * @var GetStockItemConfigurationInterface
     */
    private GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration;
    /**
     * @var GetProductSalableQtyInterface
     */
    private GetProductSalableQtyInterface $getProductSalableQty;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        StockResolverInterface $stockResolver,
        GetStockItemConfigurationInterface $getStockItemConfiguration,
        GetProductSalableQtyInterface $getProductSalableQty
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->stockResolver = $stockResolver;
        $this->getStockItemConfiguration = $getStockItemConfiguration;
        $this->getProductSalableQty = $getProductSalableQty;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isBackOrder(string $sku)
    {
        try {
            $websiteCode = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getCode();
            $stock = $this->stockResolver->execute(SalesChannelInterface::TYPE_WEBSITE, $websiteCode);
            $stockId = $stock->getStockId();

            $stockItemConfiguration = $this->getStockItemConfiguration->execute($sku, $stockId);
            $salableQty = $this->getProductSalableQty->execute($sku, $stockId);
            $threshold = $stockItemConfiguration->getMinQty();
            if ($threshold < 0) {
                $salableQty += $stockItemConfiguration->getMinQty();
            }

            if ($stockItemConfiguration->isManageStock() && $stockItemConfiguration->getBackorders() && !($salableQty > 1)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (\Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Exception\SkuIsNotAssignedToStockException $e) {
            return false;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```